# Get selected term level

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata, event-receivers, term-store

I've got a "Managed Metadata" column on a document library (required field). When I've added a document, I need to get te level of the selected term in my term store. I'm using a eventreceiver. I know how to get the value of the selected term, but not how to get the level...

**Example:**

- TermSetName     --> level 0
  -- Term1 --> level 1
  -- Term2 --> level 1
  --- Term2.1 --> level 2
  --- Term2.2 --> level 2
  --- Term2.3 --> level 2
  -- Term3 --> level 1

So when I select Term2.2, I want to get the level: 2
Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Can you help how can you get the value of selected term, and set it in textfield. thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have got hold of Term object, you can call its GetPath method to get a list of its ancestor separated by semi column(;). You can then split and find the index of last item in the split array. Check GetPath method here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee584878.aspx